# View a specific image from the complete gallery path without browsing

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm trying:

```
   <Image Source="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test/IMG_20200408_085036.jpg"/>
```

No effect.
File imageSpc = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test/IMG_20200408_085036.jpg');
var imageSpc = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test/IMG_20200408_085036.jpg');
Error, cannot create static variable for type File or var.

```
            <Image x:Name="fotka" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest = "50"
    WidthRequest = "60"/>
```

fotka.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test/IMG_20200408_085036.jpg");
No effect
Is possible to show specific image from gallery in XAML or at least from the code

[image]

I did enable ADB notification option in device.
In The moment image to be displayed compiler show error:

[image]

How to fix this Error?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to display image using gallery path, if yes, please take a look the following code:

Firstly, you need to get image path from gallery in Android or ios.

Create interface IFileSystem in PCL(Forms)

```
public interface IFileSystem
{       
     string GetGalleryImage();
}
```

Then implementing this interface in platform, the example is in Android.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileSystemImplementation))]
namespace demo3.Droid
{
public class FileSystemImplementation : IFileSystem
{

    public string GetGalleryImage()
    {      
        var filePath = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath.AbsolutePath, "Test/image1.jpg");
        return path;
    }
}
}
```

Add one Image control in PCL(Forms), name image1, using DependencyService to get image path.

```
  <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="load image" />
        <Image
            x:Name="image1"
            HeightRequest="100"
            WidthRequest="100" />

  private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        var path = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().GetGalleryImage();
        image1.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
    }
```

This is article about DependencyService, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but my Class Environment does not contain GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory and also DirectoryPictures methods. My Environment contain only GetFolderPath and GetLogicalDrives related to storage manipulations. Min Android I have set to Lolipop compiled with Pie. Both Permissions R/W is enabled.

Comment: @TamteeTa I use Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures) in Android project and don't have any problem, so please take a look my sample at github:https://github.com/CherryBu/ImageGallery

Comment: I tested this code without any errors or warning. App on device shows only Button Load Image. After click on button will nothing happend. I thing that problem is more deeply. Very detailed info by compiling will help me but all detailed options are in compilator enabled, without any errors or warning on output console, this is maybe basic problem.
Image Path on input to Button is correct and Image of course exist.

Comment: @Tamtee When you click Button for the first time, you will get permission to read device file, then you need to click button again to load image from Gallery.

Comment: Yes, the permissions have granted  on  app first running. Similar app in Kotlin and AS work normally. Im new in Xamarin and don't have a experience with debug Xamarin project.

Comment: @Tamtee Now you still have some problem when clicking button to load image from gallery? If not, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, problem still always the same. 
        private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystem>().GetGalleryImage();
            image1.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
        }
    }
In variable "path" is correct path to existing image and Btn1 not respond on click. By click is nothing to happen.

Comment: @Tamtee Please check the path **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Test/image1.jpg** is correct or not, whether there is image1.jpg in your decive. because I don't have any problems when testing project in my device, please take a look gif on my reply .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211783/discussion-between-tamtee-and-cherry-bu-msft).

Answer (score 0):

I found, each image before show in activity must be resized to max size 4096 x 4096 px otherwise image not shown, without any errors message.